# Why bitcoin cash supply is currently 100k more than bitcoin on coinmarketcap (as of Oct 17)

Tags: bitcoin-cash, money-supply

[image]
Is it a mistake or is there a significant difference in coins generated?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

EDA (Emergency Difficulty Adjustment):

> Median Time Past of the current block and the Median Time Past of 6 blocks before has to be greater than 12 hours.
>   If so, it gets 20% easier to create proof of work. In other words, miners can find blocks 20% easier.

Source: [Jimmy Song](https://medium.com/@jimmysong/bitcoin-cash-difficulty-adjustments-2ec589099a8e)

As EDA is one way (difficulty down), miners abuse it. They stop mining, and after the EDA comes, they start mining with a big hash power. This is the cause of Bitcoin Cash's hyperinflation: ~7500 blocks ahead of BTC and `7500*10/60=1250` hours of blocks ahead.

The developers are aware of this issue, and it'll be replaced on 13th of November, by a newer difficulty algorithm.

They haven't decided which algorithm to switch, but probably it'll be Dgenr8's. [1][2]

1: https://www.yours.org/content/dgenr8-s-difficulty-adjustment-algorithm-explained-01a2de286460/

2: https://reviews.bitcoinabc.org/D622

Comment: Thank you for the correct answer, I thought something stupid :D

Answer (score 1):

This is because Bitcoin Cash is highly centralized with mining power. By allowing this to happen prior to mining becoming more decentralized the promoters stand to gain a huge potential bonus. This bonus can also help them support the price with wash trades and real trades.

This is my analysis and opinion. I'm sure bag holders will flame otherwise since the truth hurts.

Comment: They had months to make sure they had the best tested algorithm that could adjust properly, they also could have redeployed as little as a week or two once this was noticed if not planned. Instead months. The largest promoter is also the manufacturer of the majority of hashpower at the moment with the greatest ability to manipulate the ebb and flow, thus the mining rate for profitable gain. All answers should show who benefits financially.